# Beamer: a moving arrow in the front of each item

Tags: beamer, arrows, itemize

First off, please take a look at [these slides](https://www.it.uu.se/katalog/andsv164/Teaching/Material/PF_Intro_2014_AndreasSvensson.pdf):

[image]

In the slide 8 (frames 1-16) we can see an arrow moves around the items.

My question is how can I reproduce that itemize list in which an arrow can shift cyclically?

Edit:

```
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}‎
\framesubtitle{}
\begin{itemize}‎
    \item item A.‎\\
  ‎\hspace{1cm}‎ \only<1>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$}} item 1. ‎\\‎
  ‎\hspace{1cm} \only<2>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$}} item 2.‎‎
  \item item B.‎ 
\end{itemize}‎
\end{frame}‎
% To change cyclically‎
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{}‎
\framesubtitle{}
\begin{itemize}‎
    \item item A.‎\\
  ‎\hspace{1cm}‎ \only<1>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$}} item 1. ‎\\‎
  ‎\hspace{1cm} \only<2>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$}} item 2.‎‎
  \item item B.‎ 
\end{itemize}‎
\end{frame}‎
```

Comment: That seems to be as simple as using `\only<3>{\makebox[0pt][r]{$\rightarrow$}}` where you vary `<3>` depending on the slide you want the content to be on.

Comment: That's right. Thank you very much. I updated my post including a sample code of what I use to cyclically shift the arrow. I think there is a better and a more efficient way; if so, please let me know the optimal implementation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcommand<>{\itemarrow}{\mbox{}\visible#1{\llap{\color{structure}$\rightarrow$\hspace{1.5em}}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{Test}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item \itemarrow<1,4>Text one
  \item \itemarrow<2,5>Text two
  \item \itemarrow<3,6>Text three
  \item Text four
    \begin{itemize}
    \item \itemarrow<7>Text one
    \item \itemarrow<8>Text two
    \item \itemarrow<9>Text three
    \item Text four
    \end{itemize}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup.